# Sorting hashof array of datetime string in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, datetime

I was trying to sort datetimes in Perl. The datetime string is in a hash of arrays. After lots of googling I used Perl's sort function. To my surprise it worked. My code & input is below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hashofarrays;

$hashofarrays{'joe tribiani'} = ['16/3/28 13:42','XII','99.93%'];
$hashofarrays{'Ross'} = ['16/3/28 13:43','XII','76.93%'];
$hashofarrays{'sue grace'} = ['11/7/5 12:07','VI','77.58%'];

foreach my $key (   sort{$hashofarrays{$a}[0] cmp $hashofarrays{$b}[0]}      keys %hashofarrays ) {
print "$key =>", join (", ", @{$hashofarrays{$key}}), "\n";
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? If I am, how is this working?

If it is wrong then what should I do to sort the date time string?

The result should list records sorted in ascending order by datetime.

The datetime format is 'YY/MM/DD' or 'YY/M/D'

My data:

```
joe tribiani, 16/3/28 13:42,XII,99.93%
Ross,16/3/28 13:43,XII,95.93%
sue grace,11/7/5 12:07,VI,77.58%
```

My excepted output:

```
sue grace =>11/7/5 12:07, VI, 77.58%
joe tribiani =>16/3/28 13:42, XII, 99.93%
Ross =>16/3/28 13:43, XII, 76.93%
```

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? Please [edit] your question and tell us what the expected order is. At the moment you are doing an ascii-betical sort on the first element of that array reference. If that date is in `YY/M/D` order that will probably work.

Comment: But given that 'M' is single digit in some cases, it won't :)

Comment: Right. I'd say parse the values to sort. Time for some Schwartzian transform.

Comment: Thank you , I added my data & expected output

Comment: Can you also tell us what the date format is? Is the first value the year or the day?

Comment: The first value is year. The date format is 'YY/MM/DD' or 'YY/M/D'.

Comment: Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What your code does

```
foreach my $key ( 
    sort { $hashofarrays{$a}[0] cmp $hashofarrays{$b}[0] }
    keys %hashofarrays 
) {
    print "$key =>", join (", ", @{$hashofarrays{$key}}), "\n";
}
```

This uses the keys of the hash to sort the elements of the hash on the first element of the array reference that's inside of that key in the hash. It uses `cmp`, which is an *ascii-betical* sorting rather than a numerical one. That means that `10` will come before `2` because `1` is a lower character than `2`.

For date sorting, this makes sense. But because your date format is not consistently with two digits for months and days, it will not sort properly.

```
18/5/1    # sorted last
18/10/1   # sorted first
```

For those two dates, the later October date will be sorted first which is wrong.

### What you need to do instead

If you cannot clean up the input data, you need to process it to figure out the value behind the date instead of relying on the presentation for sorting. Parsing dates is its own problem, and we'll use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to do it, which has been in the Perl core for a while now.

We could do it like this pseudo-code:

```
sort { parse($a) <=> parse($b) } ...
```

That would work, but would be slow, especially for a larger number of records, because it parses the date with every comparison. If you don't know how sorting works internally, it compares values to each other, maybe changes position of the two values, and repeats.

There is a way of making this more efficient, but it's a bit more complex.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my %values = ( 'joe tribiani' => [ '16/3/28 13:42', 'XII', '99.93%' ],
               'Ross'         => [ '16/3/28 13:43', 'XII', '76.93%' ],
               'sue grace'    => [ '11/7/5 12:07',  'VI',  '77.58%' ], );

my @sorted_keys = map { $_->[1] }
    sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
    map {
        [ Time::Piece->strptime( $values{$_}->[0], '%y/%m/%d %H:%M' )->epoch, $_ ]
    }
    keys %values;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @sorted_keys;
```

This is called the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). It essentially processes the values once, puts them into another array reference, together with the actual values that are being sorted. It then sorts on the pre-processed values, and then puts them back.

This is way more efficient, and because of the parsing it will work on all dates that might show up in your values without sorting them in the wrong way.

Note we need to use the numerical comparison operator `<=>` now, because we are sorting on *epoch* values, which are just numbers (lots of seconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00`).

Comment: Thank you. The solution is working perfect for my problem.